# Document Size Vs Documents array length in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have two solutions while modeling mongodb objects :

1. to increase the size of document by storing more fields in one document.
2. to increase number of documents by storing data separetly in different documents.

In case 1 i have to apply complex queries but the number of documents will be less.
In case 2 only simple queries are required but the number of document will be more.

which one is better in terms of speed and performance if my data scales up exponentially.

Comment: it depends on the request you plan to perform...

Comment: but still i need some comparison between these two @felix